# How to re-open closed tab?

Tags: firefox, browser-tabs

I just upgraded to Firefox 4 and can't seem to find a feature I used quite often:

*If I accidentally close a tab, I could right-click and select an option to reopen the closed tab.*

Where is this feature in Firefox 4?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Right-click on an existing tab and select `Undo Close Tab`.

The keyboard shortcut is the same: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. (Mac OS X it's <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.)

Comment: Thanks. I always used the history tab and re-opened it there. +1

Comment: Works in Google Chrome, too.

Comment: works in ie9 too

Comment: It's grayed out for me, so this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `T` doesn't work on Firefox 29. I guess they have changed this shortcut.

Comment: @Isaac: It still works for me (Windows 8).

Comment: @AlE: Now it works for me too. Either they fixed it in 29.0.1 update or I am silly negligent.

Comment: FYI: This also has been a Firefox Tip in 2012: https://blog.mozilla.org/theden/2012/07/26/shortcut-to-reopen-closed-tabs/

Comment: Is it possible to change this to Command+Z like in Safari?

Answer (score 7):

If I click the "Firefox" button I can still navigate to History > Recently Closed Tabs.

Answer (score 2):

Al Everett is correct. 
If you are looking for the shortcut in a Mac OS X system, it's
<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I personally use an add-on called Tab Mix Plus. Among other things, it allows you to restore tabs by showing a "recently closed tabs" list when you right-click the tab bar.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a shortcut you might want to use a button.
In this case you need an add-on. As it has already been mentioned there is "Tab Mix Plus", which has this feature. Additionally here are other Firefox add-ons with such a button:

- [Toolbar buttons](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/toolbar-buttons)
- [Undo Closed Tabs Button](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/toolbar-buttons) (no other buttons)
- And for Firefox for Android there also is [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/mobile/addon/reopen-last-closed-tab/), but unfortunately it seems to be outdated and not compatible with the latest Firefox version.

Answer (score -1):

I also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>, but can't work out if it's a Firefox standard or from an add-on.

Comment: Must be an add-on; doesn't work for me.

Comment: that's [tab mix plus'](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-mix-plus/) hotkey (also @AlEverett)